# How do you perform renewal pricing comparison on the domain name you already owned

Tags: domain-registration

Last year, I just purchased 2 domain names from a domain registrar company.

Now, my owned domain names are going to expire in few more months. When I decide to continue to renew the domain names with them, I realize they increase the renewal price for more than 100%

I want to know what price I will pay for, if I renew the domain names with other domain registrar companies. However, when I perform such checking on the other domain registrar companies' websites, they will state that the domain names is not available. (As I'm still owning them)

So, may I know, how can I perform renewal pricing comparison on the domain name I already owned, and not yet expired?

Comment: They _should_ publish a **price list** of registration and renewal costs. If they aren't upfront about their pricing I would look elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

To get customers most of domains providers sell domain at huge discount and at time renewal they charge normal charge. That's why it looks high.

Price of domain registration with different extension like `.com`, `.org` is different.

At time of domain renewal, as you increase year of subscription price hosting provide could give you discount but it depends on service provider.

Answer (score 1):

The questioner appears to be asking how he can compare the cost to renew his domain with the cost to transfer it at different registrars, since his domain will appear as "unavailable" if attempted to be searched on or registered.

With his current registrar, the renewal price will most likely be higher than he initially registered it for, especially if he used a discount or introductory offer. He can simply add the domain to renew to his registrar's shopping cart without paying for it in order to see the renewal cost. Often there are discount or "promo" codes available for different registrars if searched for in Google which will lower the renewal cost somewhat.

Even with a discount, renewal fees for registrars are almost always higher than their introductory registration fees - that's how they build business. Some will provide a 1 year introductory offer or discount for transferring a domain too, but the subsequent years will be at their renewal rate, which can usually be found on their websites, typically in smaller print like a footnote.

In order to confirm the price or discount to transfer a domain, you have to first unlock the domain with your current registrar (be sure to lock it after you're done). Then the domain will say "available" to transfer instead of unavailable.

Tip: It's a good idea to turn off "autorenew" for the domain(s) if you plan on shopping discounted transfer rates. However, be extra careful not to let the domain expire or you may end paying an exorbitant "redemption" fee, or even losing the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I usually look for their annual price on a domain as that's typically the renewal price, and if you see an asterisk, just follow that and see what is stated to find out if the renewal price is different. Most registrars allow free account creation, and from there you can usually start a transfer without actually initiating it to just see what the price is.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the pricing page. Look for your TLD and, look for renewal price. If there is a discount or such thing, just ignore those price and search another page. The domain name with the same TLD usually will have the same price.